# android asynctask for httpconnection

Tags: android, httpclient, android-asynctask

can any one please tell me how to fix this problem .... why is it not working 
 im trying to asynctask the connection to a server so it can be on separate thread

```
private class SticketFunctionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... string) {

    try {

//public void  SticketFunction(){
    //HttpClient
    HttpClient SpeedSticket = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //Response handler
    ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();

    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.php");
    //Log.v("log_tag", "+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+- Done: HTTP Post Sending Stickit to Server");
    //Log.v("log_tag", "+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+- sTICKET: " + z.getString(1) + " " + z.getString(2) + " " + z.getString(3) + " " + z.getString(4));

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bookName", z.getString(1)+""));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bookAuth", z.getString(2)+""));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ISBN", z.getString(3)+""));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LibNumber", z.getString(4)+""));
        //Encode and set entity
        postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
        //Execute 
        String response = SpeedSticket.execute(postMethod, res).replaceAll("<(.|\n)*?>","");
        if (response.equals("Done")){

            //Log.v("log_tag", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! SticketFunction got a DONE!");

        }
        else Log.v("log_tag", "!!!!!!!?????????? SticketFunction Bad or no response: " + response);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        //Log.v("log_tag", "???????????????????? SticketFunction Client Exception");
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //Log.v("log_tag", "???????????????????? IO Exception");
    } 
}
    }
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: its the third bracket from the end (Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete 
 BlockStatements)

Comment: it is a syntax error you need to add a finally { } block

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse, select all of the code and go to Source -> Correct Indentation (or press Ctrl-I). Then you will see that you have a two try blocks, but the two catch blocks belong to the second try. So you need a catch or finally block for the first try.

I think the easiest fix is to delete the line with the second try.